# Count different status in my sql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields:

```
Date    
EmpId   
TimeIn  
TimeOut 
Status
```

Its an attendance table. Basically I need to calculate the payroll (I've got the salary and deductions in another table). By counting each type of status for each employee with in a particular range or the full last month.

I need the output in the following format:

```
EmpID|Days Present|Days Late|Days Absent| After TimeIn A| After TimeIn B|
```

The Status field contains the status of the employee ie. present, late, absent, for that particular day depending on the time in etc.

I just cant crack this. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do the `Status` field mean?

Comment: what an awful draconian system....

Answer (score 11):

Since you didn't specify how the `Status` column is enumerated, I made some assumptions. Obviously you'll need to substitute the correct values in each CASE statement.

```
SELECT EmpId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Days Present`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Late' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Days Late`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Days Absent`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'After A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `After Timein A`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'After B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `After Timein B`
    FROM Attendance
    WHERE Date >= {Your Start Date}
        AND Date <= {Your End Date}
    GROUP BY EmpId
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I'll try it out and see how it goes. Once again thanks!